# Handlebars JS if statement not working

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars templating engine to output a load of data.

I'm trying to use an if statement to only show the first ten iritations. Is this possible?

Below is what I have so far.

```
{{#if @index > 10}}
    <div style="display:none;">
{{else}}
    <div>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register a helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("onlyten",function(arr,options) {
    if(options.inverse && !arr.length)
        return options.inverse(this);

    return arr.map(function(item,index) {
        item.$dontshow = index > 10;
        return options.fn(item);
    }).join('');
});
```

and use it like

```
{{#onlyten yourArray}}
    <div{{#if $dontshow}} style="display: none;"{{/if}}></div>
{{/onlyten}}
```